# PROC TABULATE Rearrange header subgroups independent of the data

Tags: sorting, sas, proc

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479668/sas-proc-tabulate-rearrange-header-subgroups/) which considered only a single variable with two subgroups.  In that question, the solution was to order the subgroups by sorting the data.

That approach, however, breaks down when there are several variables.  It becomes a whack-a-mole of sorting the variables into a sequence which produces the desired result.  Each subsequent `BY` variable subgroup depends on the previous levels.  If not all subgroups are present in a higher level group, then not all subgroups can be arranged into the desired order.

Either `PROC TABULATE` is not the appropriate tool for this task (i.e. obtaining percents of various groups across several variables) or there is a technique that allows for subgroups to be arranged independently of the data.

Do I go digging for the needle in the documentation haystack or do I reinvent the wheel?  Any insights you could give me would be appreciated.

---

**Example:**

To give an illustration, say that I want to create a table with the subgroups of each variable arranged in (Y, N) order.  Notice how `var4` is not output in the correct order.  By the time the other variables have been sorted, there aren't enough `var4` values present to be sorted into the desired order.

```
data example;
    input group $ var1 $ var2 $ var3 $ var4 $;
    datalines;
    1 Y Y N Y
    1 N Y N N
    2 Y N Y N
    2 Y Y Y N
    3 N N N Y
    3 N Y Y N
    ;
run;

proc sort data = example out = sorted;
    by  descending var1
        descending var2
        descending var3
        descending var4
        ;
run;

title 'Percent';
proc tabulate data = sorted order = data;
    class group var1 var2 var3 var4;
    table group='Group', 
            all  = 'Total'*pctn='' 
            var1 = 'Variable 1'*pctn=''
            var2 = 'Variable 2'*pctn=''
            var3 = 'Variable 3'*pctn=''
            var4 = 'Variable 4'*pctn='';
run;
```

[image: Program Output]

It may be possible to devise a combination of `BY` variables in the `PROC SORT` which give a (Y, N) subgrouping order, but it would involve a bunch of fiddling which is not robust against changes in data. If the table needs to be updated monthly, then each month you would have to fiddle with the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

No workaround or reinventing the wheel required - this is exactly what classdata datasets are for:

```
data example;
    input group (var1-var4) ($1. +1);
    datalines;
    1 Y Y N Y
    1 N Y N N
    2 Y N Y N
    2 Y Y Y N
    3 N N N Y
    3 N Y Y N
    ;
run;

data classtypes;
    do group = 1 to 3;
        do var1 = 'Y','N';
            do var2 = 'Y','N';      
                do var3 = 'Y','N';                  
                    do var4 = 'Y','N';
                        output;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;            
    end;
run;

title 'Percent';
proc tabulate data = example order = data classdata=classtypes;
    class group var1 var2 var3 var4;
    table group='Group', 
            all  = 'Total'*pctn='' 
            var1 = 'Variable 1'*pctn=''
            var2 = 'Variable 2'*pctn=''
            var3 = 'Variable 3'*pctn=''
            var4 = 'Variable 4'*pctn='';
run;
```

As a bonus, this also avoids having to sort your main input dataset - row/column order in the output table is determined by the order of the classdata dataset.

Comment: Thank you.  For future readers, the `+1` in the `INPUT` statement is a "Column Pointer Control" which moves the pointer *n* columns.  In this case, it moves the pointer to the next data value.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach only works for small numbers of variables, each with only a few subgroups.  It works well for four variables with two subgroups apiece.  This makes `classtypes` have 48 observations.  But the more variables and subgroups there are, the larger the `classtypes` becomes.  For 16 variables with subgroups of size 6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 2, 2, 2, 10, 8, and 10 each, the `classtypes` table then has 117,964,800 observations.  This takes me 6 minutes to print the table, in addition to the 7 it takes to generate `classtypes` itself. And `classtypes` is 26.2Gb.

Comment: If you have constraints on what combinations of values are possible, you can code those into the classdata definition. Beyond a certain point, I'd suggest splitting your data out over a number of smaller, more readable tables.